# Does ArcGIS Desktop have similar tool to QGIS Clip raster by Mask layer which creates and outputs alpha band on request?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, extract-by-mask

This QGIS tool creates an alpha band by clipping an image with a polygon.

https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdalogr/gdal_extraction/cliprasterbymasklayer.html

Is there an equivalent tool in ArcGIS 10x?

Comment: Because you want a transparent background in ArcGIS?  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/130121/export-geotif-with-transparent-background

Answer (score 1):

You can use the 'Extract by Mask' tool (under Spatial Analyst Tools in the ArcToolbox) in ArcGIS Desktop 10.x and ArcGIS Pro to achieve this. Though keep in mind, you may need a specific license to use this tool.

Check this out: https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.5/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/extract-by-mask.htm

The process is similar to that in QGIS. You select the tool (Extract by Mask) which prompts you to draw the shape of the desired raster you would like to extract. You then input the layer of the original layer, use the polygon you created as the clip layer, and name the output layer and the directory which you would like to send it to.